# Check if the checkbox is checked

Tags: css

I want to create the next logic: when i will check the checkbox to apply a background for another element. I want to do this using only css.

```css
div{
  border:1px solid red
}
input:checked .parent {
  background:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <label for="">Text</label>
  <input type='checkbox'>
</div>
```

So i want to apply a background for `.parent` when i check the checkbox, but this doesn't work. Who knows how to solve this?

Comment: @Roy, no, because in my case  i cant change the html. I don't have acces

Comment: @epanalepsis, i'm looking for an answer which uses only css, not JQUERY

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<div class="parent">
  <label for="">Text</label>
  <input type='checkbox'>
</div>
```

CSS

```
div{
  border:1px solid red
}
.selected{
  background:red;
}
```

JQuery

```
 $('input:checkbox').change(function(){
   if($(this).is(':checked')) 
       $(this).parent().addClass('selected'); 
  else 
      $(this).parent().removeClass('selected')
 });
```

Output

[image]

Comment: i'm looking for an answer which uses only css, not JQUERY